# How to create form to sort images when Admin creates new product?

Tags: html, forms, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `Product` class and an `Image` class.
These 2 classes have a ***1:many*** **relationship**. Each `Product` has many `Image`*`s`*, like this:

| Product | T-Shirt |
| --- | --- |
| Images | Image_T-shirt_1.png |
| Images | Image_T-shirt_2.jpeg |
| Images | Image_T-shirt_3.png |

| Product | Basketball |
| --- | --- |
| Images | Image_basketball.png |

I want to create a form so the **Admin** when creating the new product, can sort the order of the images when it appears on the **details** page for the end-user.

It should look like this when navigating to `https://abc.xyz/Products/SortImages/37`:
[image: Ability to sort images]

What you see in white in the photo, is the text box, so the Admin can type in the number of the order of the images.